# Asp Mvc Data not being passed from View To Controller Uing Html Form and Submit Button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Here is complete code
the values of input box are not being passed to session variables

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("View11" );
    }
```

**Index2 Code**
       below
        Here data is being not recieved

```
public ActionResult Index2()
            {
                Session["s1"] = Request.Form["My"];
                   Session["s2"] = Request.Form["My2"]; 


                return View("View2");
            }

  View1 Code
```

html code View1

```
 <form name="form1" action="/Home/index2" method="post">
                <input  name="My" type="text"  />
                <input   name="My2" type="text"  />
                <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
                  </form>

Index2 Code Ended

View2 Code--->

    below
  <div> 
@Session["s1"] 
 @Session["s2"]

   </div>
```

Can someone tell me that why Session Variable is still null

Comment: Your view doesn't *have* a form.  So how do you expect it to be posting form values?

Comment: *View1 Code** <form name="form1" action="index2" method="post"> <input name="My" type="text" /> <input name="My2" type="text" /> <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /> </form>

Comment: You may want to include that code *in the question*.  That form would post those two values.  While in MVC you wouldn't want to use `Request.Form`, it would still technically work.  What is the specific sequence of events taking place here and in what specific way is it failing?

Comment: Ok So  i had problem in getting values from view to Controller

Comment: You're going to have to actually describe the problem.  Include the *actual code* in the question, specify the steps you've taken, and explain *specifically* where it's failing.  Form values get posted to the server, this is standard functionality.  If that's not working for you then you're doing something wrong.  Nobody here can know what unless you describe it.

Comment: Here Was Rest of code                                                                        **Index1 Code**
      public ActionResult Index()
    { 
            return View("View1");
     } View1 Code{
       < form name=form1" action="index2" method="post">
               <     input  name="My" type="text"  >
                  <  input   name="My2" type="text"  >
                  <  input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" >
                   <   /form>
    }

Comment: You are entirely misunderstanding how Stack Overflow works.  We don't exchange email addresses and provide private tutoring services.  If you have information to add to the question, add it *to the question*.  And you're going to have to *very specifically* describe exactly what you're doing and what behavior you're seeing from the code, because there is *nothing* wrong with that form.

Comment: ok i updated my question , kindly check it one more time

Comment: David , thanks i got my the values , actually i was putting the <form> in html document   and i would not put it inside html document then it will work fine , but i am not sure why any thoughts?

Comment: Form elements are HTML and belong in HTML documents.  Whatever you're doing wrong, nobody here can know without you sharing that information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid, your code should be as follows:

```
<form action="/Home/SubmitForm" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The above is a basic form. Our `action` declaration states the `Home` Controller, with the method `SubmitForm`. You use the `name` attribute to allow Model View Controller (MVC) to automatically pass the parameter to the Controller.  So the `name` on your element should match the parameter of the Controller.

Your Controller code would simply be the following:

```
public class HomeController
{
     public ActionResult SubmitForm(string username)
     {
          // Do Something
          return View();
     }
}
```

Our `Controller` would perform an action then return our desired `View` state.  What your URL would represent:

- Page Url: sample.com/Home
- Submitting Form: sample.com/Home?username=userinput

You don't want to use `Session`, that would create a global variable in essence which will reside in your server memory.  Which means enough could degrade performance, while also create state related issues with your data.  However, your code could work with the proper form declaration.  However, the proper approach is more a long the lines outlined above.